# Turtle Function not being implemented

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

After finding a solution to my earlier question, I have been faced for a couple hours with a new problem with my Turtle functions. I am new to Python and turtle so I am not sure of the syntax that is needed for where to put commands (i.e. before or after defining the function) so that they will be implemented in the turtle module since I am trying to simulate a random turtle race, but it just keeps on coming up with the blank turtle screen with a black turtle in the center. What I am doing thats preventing the commands from working? So far thisis what I have but I would like to at least know I am getting the first part correct before I try to go any further with the rest:

```
import turtle
import random

t = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
v = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
s = turtle.Screen()
s.exitonclick()

def setup(turtle1, turtle2, s):
    t = turtle1
    v = turtle2
    s.setworldcoordinates(0,0,50,50)
    t.setposition(1,25)
    t.up()
    v.setposition(1,25)
    v.up()
    t.color('red')
    v.color('red')
    s = turtle.Screen()
    s.exitonclick()


def newHeading(turtle, angleOfTipsiness):
    t.setheading(random.randrange(-angleOfTipsiness, angleOfTipsiness))
    v.setheading(random.randrange(-angleOfTipsiness, angleOfTipsiness))
```

I need the beginning picture to look like this : http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~buoni/cs8/labs/lab02/start.JPG

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually *calling* either the `setup` or the `newHeading` function. At the end of your code, you should have a top-level block looking like this:

```
# ...

def newHeading(turtle, angleOfTipsiness):
    t.setheading(random.randrange(-angleOfTipsiness, angleOfTipsiness))
    v.setheading(random.randrange(-angleOfTipsiness, angleOfTipsiness))

# after the end of the function definitions, add this:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # example calls, replace with ones that make sense for what
    # you're trying to do:
    setup(t, v, s)
    newHeading(t, 10)
```

Several remarks on the code:

- Your `setup` function should use the parameters `turtle1` and `turtle2`, not assign them to new local variables `t` and `v`. (If the function parameters are too long to type over and over, just give them shorter names.) Likewise, `newHeading` doesn't use the `turtle` parameter at all.
- `t` and `v` are confusing names for local variables because you already have global variables with the same names.
- Global variables should be given long and descriptive names. Short names should be reserved for local variables, which are used more often, and in a more limited context.

In general, your function can either access the global variable and use the contained object as a global resource, or it can accept the object as a parameter and use it that way. Both are valid choices for some situations (the former is simpler, the latter more reusable), but you should not mix the two. If something is a global variable, don't also pass it as a parameter; if it is a parameter, use it instead of the global variable, even if the global is otherwise available. Mixing the two approaches for the same object will confuse the person maintaining the code later.

Comment: Ok, I Understand what you are saying about calling them different variables, I changed that, but for adding an if statement, I don't know what it would be since I am not trying to get it to move with this function, I am just setting it up so that it would be in place. The way it would be in place if it wasn't under a definition. And so that the color would also be apparent.

Comment: @MoniqueWilliams Obviously, functions are only useful when they are called, and you are not calling the `setup` and `newHeading` functions. The additional code that I proposed should be placed at the very bottom of your module (not inside a function), and does exactly what you want: execute the code in the functions the way it would be if it wasn't under a definition. If you want something different to happen, please try to explain the desired outcome as clearly as possible.

Comment: And `s.exitonclick()` needs to go as the last instruction

Comment: Can someone tell me why I am getting the error messages TclError: can't invoke "winfo" command:  application has been destroyed